# How to get Json in Grok Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

So currently I'm building a log system using ELK Stack. Before building this ELK, I already have custom log format for my apps, so that it can be easily read by human. My log is formatted something like this

```
Method: POST
URL: https://localhost:8888/api
Body: {
   "field1":"value1",
   "field2":[
       {
            "field3":"value2",
            "field4":"value3"
       },
       {
            "field3":"value2",
            "field4":"value3"
       },
    ]
}
```

using grok pattern, I can get the Method and the URL, but how can I get the full body json in grok / logstash so that i can send them to elasticsearch?
Since the length of the json is not fixed and can be longer or shorter each log

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [JSON Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html).
It should parse the JSON for you, and put it into a structured format so you can then send it where ever you need (e.g. Elasticsearch, another pipeline)

From the docs

> It takes an existing field which contains JSON and expands it into an actual data 
>   structure within the Logstash event.

There are also some other questions here on SO that could be helpful. An example: [Using JSON with LogStash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22941739/using-json-with-logstash)